# UItableView Slide down Menu when selected?

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to have another tableview slide down when I click on a tableview cell, basically like how Snapchat does it. Can anyone explain how that would be done?

Comment: is this what you were looking for? https://github.com/tordasnes/Snapchat-clone

Comment: Yea its pretty similar thank you!